# How did my printer install itself into Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, printing

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I believe it is a Dell Latitude E5430, Bios rev. A03, 8GB RAM and 64 bits OS.

Accordingly this is all new to me and I opted for the Ubuntu Linux OS in lieu of a Win10 update crapping out my machine beyond recovery. Any how I discovered this past afternoon that I had an up and running printer having not installed any of the Brother drivers I down loaded for my MFC-J885DW. I went into the settings menu and snooped into the printer settings and discovered I had printing ability.

Early on after I installed Ubuntu to this laptop I had no printing capability. I did a test page print command from the settings menu today and got a good copy. I assume it was a mix of graphics and text.

I continued to test the printer by printing files through LibreOffice and a PDF viewer I have installed from the Ubuntu software website; and all of the printed documents were as if I had printed them from a Win10 machine, the way they should be. I think I'll have to do more graphics type of print testing to make sure about that; capability.

I guess my question is: **How is this possible without having installed the driver files I downloaded?** I also don't expect this to happen with the scanner function, although I have yet to check into that puppy.

I am wondering how!

Comment: Gee, I haven't had to install a printer driver manually in so many years...I had forgotten that particular type of pain.

Answer (score 2):

Linux was the pioneer of the driverless install.  Instead of having to run some proprietary code to run your devices, volunteers and manufacturers made the code (and frequently the technical documentation) available publicly.  This allowed the developers to include (and make more efficient code for) all the possible devices you might want to plug into your machine.  No need to dig around  the internet (or your disk drawer) for (frequently outdated) drivers!

Ubuntu also comes with the Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) preinstalled.  CUPS sits in the background looking for printer-specific hardware changes.  If your printer was plugged in via USB, then CUPS would automatically set it up for you to use.  If your printer is network-enabled, then CUPS will actively seek it out at regular intervals.

While it isn't always prefect (and there's lots of work always going on in the background), it's one of those things that put Linux well ahead of the curve.  Even Windows now does it this way, albeit with an internet-required driver library instead of an efficient all-encompassing codebase.